How would I make GHC.Ptr an instance of Monad?
This is what I have so far:
instance Monad Ptr where
    return = pure
    (>>=) (Ptr t) f = f t 

The error being thrown is:
    • Couldn't match a lifted type with an unlifted type
      When matching types
        a :: *
        GHC.Prim.Addr# :: TYPE 'GHC.Types.AddrRep
    • In the first argument of ‘f’, namely ‘t’
      In the expression: f t
      In an equation for ‘>>=’: (>>=) (Ptr t) f = f t
    • Relevant bindings include
        f :: a -> Ptr b (bound at RegionalMemory.hs:16:19)
        (>>=) :: Ptr a -> (a -> Ptr b) -> Ptr b
          (bound at RegionalMemory.hs:16:5)
   |
16 |     (>>=) (Ptr t) f = f t
   |                         ^

I do not quite understand this error. What am I doing wrong here?

This is not exactly a duplicate

t is not of type a, but an Addr#ess, so you don't.

So, in short, there is no way? :(

I think it makes more sense to ask: what would be the use-case here?

I was trying out my hand at using ccall to allocate and deallocate memory regions from inside haskell as a project and I was hoping to be able to use either the bind or the sequencing operators on the allocation functions. What I ended up doing was defining my own special operator to achieve that task. I guess that is what I needed all along?

What is the type of your special operator?

Possibly related question: what should (>>=) do when it's asked to return a Ptr to a non-Storable type?

With sufficient tomfoolery, it is possible to make a type-correct instance of Monad for data PtrToBe a where PtrToBe :: Storable x => IO (Ptr x, x -> a) -> PtrToBe a, but I am somewhat skeptical that it would pass the monad laws and extremely skeptical that what it does is actually sensible or useful. After all, half the tomfoolery is coming up with that type in the first place; it's very unnatural.

@DanielWagner (-->) :: Ptr (Ptr ()) -> (Ptr () -> Ptr (Ptr ())) -> Ptr (Ptr ()) which is basically a bind operator.

@kesarling I'm shocked that there's an interesting implementation of that (i.e. not x --> _ = x); all the interesting Ptr operations involve IO.

yeah, it is something on the lines of alloc_store --> read_at_offset --> write_at_offset --> ...

Also, I just realized a grave mistake. The function should take Ptr (Ptr ()) instead of Ptr ()... that explains the segfault lmao

t is not of type a, but an Addr#ess, so you don't. Indeed, the Ptr data type is defined as [Haskell-src]:

data Ptr a = Ptr Addr#
  deriving ( Eq  -- ^ @since base-2.01
           , Ord -- ^ @since base-2.01
           )


The a does not tell what the type of the value wrapped in the data constructor is, it tells what kind of thing the address refers to.
So we can not make this work, we don't get the "result" of the address to pass as parameter.
